# Using whatwg-fetch with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, fetch, polyfills

In the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch#importing) for `whatwg-fetch` it says:

> Importing will automatically polyfill window.fetch and related APIs:
>
> ```
> import 'whatwg-fetch'
>
> window.fetch(...)
> ```

Below that in the same section it says

> For use with webpack, add this package in the entry configuration
>   option before your application entry point:
>
> ```
> entry: ['whatwg-fetch', ...]
> ```

I use `webpack`.

**Should I both import it and add it as an entry, or is the entry enough?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One or the other, they will produce the same output anyways. I suggest importing in your entry point other than adding on the entry array on your webpack configuration.